# Does D have an equivalent to C++ nullptr_t?

Tags: null, d, ambiguity

in C++, I can do this:

```
void func(void *something) {
    cout << "something" << endl;
}

void func(nullptr_t) {
    cout << "nullptr_t" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int nothing = 5;
    func(&nothing);
    func(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

> something
>   nullptr_t

so I can special case nullptr_t.

In D, I have two functions:

```
void func(void* pod) {
    cout << "pod" << endl;
}

void func(Object obj) {
    cout << "Object" << endl;
}
```

So how do I resolve the ambiguity when calling `func(null)`?

Comment: Please don't use nullptr_t to resolve ambiguities. Make the caller mention the type explicitly, either by casting or assigning it to a variable first.

Comment: Because this will _only_ work for literals. Chances are, if someone calls your function with a `null` literal they meant to select one of the two overloads, not a `nullptr_t` overload. And by providing a `nullptr_t` overload you're silently discarding that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void func(typeof(null)) {}
```

The null literal is a special type in D, which you can specifically get with the `typeof` operator.

Note that this will only catch a `null` *literal* - it will not catch a null Object or null pointer variable.

Comment: Imagine the surprise if we found out that D implemented dependent types just for this case...